# Update lines with data of the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

i have a global table called item_empresa, in this table i have some colums called preco, preco_1 and there we go.
This item_empresa table has two ID's: id_item and id_empresa
I have to update the table data where the id_empresa is different. For example:

```
UPDATE item_empresa SET
preco = (SELECT preco FROM item_empresa WHERE id_empresa = 1)
WHERE id_empresa = 2;
```

I Need something that would 'copy' the preco data from the item_empresa with id_empresa = 1, to the preco data of the item_empresa with id_empresa = 2.
Making this changes in all the lines of the table item_empresa.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: What's wrong with the query you have? Sample data and expected results might help too.

Comment: Actually i'm getting the error that my subquery returned more than one row, using this type of query.

Comment: It's expected something like:
preco(item_empresa(id_empresa = 2)) receives the value of the  preco(item_empresa(id_empresa = 1))

Comment: I have to update 392 lines in this table. That's the issue

Comment: I'm using Postgres SQL 10

Comment: What if item_empresa contains multipe rows with id_empresa=1. In that case which row's preco should be assigned to the rows with id_empresa = 2

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is that your *SELECT* query is returning more than one line. I'm not sure why, but you probably have multiple lines with the same id_empresa. 
If all these "repeated" lines have the same values, you might find it useful to use a *GROUP BY* condition.

```
UPDATE item_empresa SET
preco = (SELECT preco FROM item_empresa WHERE id_empresa = 1 GROUP BY id_empresa)
WHERE id_empresa = 2;
```

If the vaules of the lines are not the same, then you will need to find a way to pick the one you actually want. Try adding more conditions in the *WHERE* call.